# Is there a way to debug interactively with the C-Spy command line utility?

Tags: debugging, command-line, embedded, iar

I have a ST board and I would like to debug it with the C-Spy command line utility. When I launch C-Spy via the generated .bat file in the /settings folder the board is flashed and the program gets executed just fine. The problem is that I am not able to enter any command inside the c-spy utility and control it interactively while debugging.

I read the IAR article about the [C-Spy command line utility](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/test-your-code-from-the-command-line-using-cspybat/), but there is no information about breakpoints, or any other debug feature, besides standard output.

Than I read the article about [C-Spy command line debugging](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/debugger/cspybat-command-line-debugging-fails/), which is completly useless, because it says **nothing** about how to debug with the command line, and finally i read the user manual where there is still no word about setting breakpoints or any other feature which would enable basic debugging.

At that point I am not even sure if you can do debugging with C-Spy on the command line interactively.

Comment: Do you mean interactively or all done through a bat file?

Comment: @RussSchultz i mean interactively. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to debug with the `cspybat` command line utility *interactively*.
It is possible to make use of the C-SPY macro language to *automatically* set and modify breakpoints etc. as specified by a script.

The IAR article [Introduction to debugging with C-SPY macros](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/introduction-to-debugging-with-c-spy-macros/) looks like a good starting point.

`cspybat` accepts script files using the command line argument `--macro filename`.

Comment: Thank you very much that helps me a lot. I have seen the option to set breakpoints with macro file but I ignored it after reading into it, because i would have needed to interact with c-spy while debugging. The reasons for this is, because i am trying to write a debug adapter plugin for visual studio code which would let you debug with c-spy inside vscode. But if there is no way of interacting with c-spy that idea is basically dead now.